# What is the "bolillero" called in English?

Tags: nouns, translation, image-identification

In lottery games or bingo games, sometimes an object like this is used:

[image: bolillero]

What is the name of this? In Spanish we call it *bolillero* but I couldn’t find the definition in English.

Comment: A similar-looking manually operated device for bingo is called a "bingo ball dispenser" in [this online advertisement](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bingo+ball+dispenser%22&lr&as_qdr=all&tbm=isch&imgil=17o4QflgiG-f9M%253A%253BOXvNtYnBpXzZcM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.amazon.co.uk%25252FBINGO-LOTTO-CARDS-COVERING-DISPENSER%25252Fdp%25252FB005KJEZNE&source=iu&pf=m&fir=17o4QflgiG-f9M%253A%252COXvNtYnBpXzZcM%252C_&usg=__kn61b3Z2XkQReyM1EU4Asc_urSc%3D&biw=1058&bih=1018&ved=0ahUKEwjqzpvWoNXUAhVX62MKHcJdBBwQyjcImgE&ei=SrZNWeqBEdfWjwPCu5HgAQ#imgrc=17o4QflgiG-f9M:).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called a *lottery drum* ([source](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=790225)) or a *lottery machine* ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_machine)).

Comment: I think a lottery (or raffle) drum tends to be [cylindrical](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/raffle-drum). One vendor seems to call an electric version of the device that the poster asks about a [number picking machine](https://www.ebay.com/i/291932927603?chn=ps&dispItem=1).

Answer (score 9):

This one says it is called "bingo cage" or "lottery spinner".

[image: bingo cage]

Comment: Would have helped if you cited your source?

Comment: sorry ... http://www.etsy.com/listing/106934095/vintage-metal-bingo-cage-lottery-drawing